# "Convert to red button" to change text color to red and then again to its original color

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

i want the "convert to red button" to change text to red (in preview para) and again to primary color according to theme like black in light theme,and white in blue and black background but in my code it is not happeniong with light theme[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSCCy.png)

i tried multiple code logics with the function redcol but that not working

```
const redcol = () => {
    // Check the current color
    if (incolor.color === 'red') {
        // Toggle the text color based on the background and theme
        if (document.body.style.backgroundColor === 'black' || props.mode === 'dark') {
            setupcolor({ color: 'white' });
        } else {
            setupcolor({ color: 'black' });
        }
    } else {
        setupcolor({ color: 'red' });
    }
    props.showAlert("Toggled text color", "success");
};
```

Comment: it'd be easier probably to do this by adding and removing a class when you want the color to change. When the class is removed, the element will go back to its previous state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be easily like this:

```
const App = () => {
  const [isRed, setIsRed] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setIsRed(!isRed)}>Change Color</button>
      <br/>
      <p style={{ color: isRed ? 'red' : 'black'}}>any text here</p>
    </>
  )
}
```

and it is better not to use or change document object yourself . react has it's own virtual DOM . so it is better to use states and other hooks to change styles, values, and  ...